# Add jupyter (classic) or jupyter lab as a page in my django or Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, django, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter-lab

I am building a small web app that is used to manage data science projects. I am currently using Django for the web app. I want a user to be able to open a jupyter notebook from inside my app. I know this sort of behavior is possible because I can use jupyter inside my PyCharm IDE. I don't wanna use Iframes (this will be the last resort.) I can't find any documentation on how to integrate with the server. Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Ideally you should show things you have tried rather than ask the community to do it for you.